# Django 2.1 - CSRFToken change

Tags: django

Im having a problem migrating my DJANGO application from 1.11 to 2.1

During development, I have a node.js server (frontend) on port 3000 and DJANGO dev server on 8000. Frontend makes Ajax call protected by CSRFtoken.

I have a view called at the fronted start with the @ensure_csrf_cookie decorator.

The first time I usually had to go to chrome://net-internals/#events
start the frontend, taking the csrftoken value returned from server and then create the relative cookie. Unfortunally the cookie is not automatically create with this configuration.

The problem is. Django 1.11 generate the same CSRFToken even after a full refresh so after the first time, the cookie will be equal to generated token.
Django 2.1 change the csrftoken every time so I'm not able to create a cookie because it will always equals to the previous value.

Why did Django 2.1 change the csrftoken even if default duration is 1 year?

Comment: I thought you might be affected by [ticket 20869](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20869). However that suggests that the tokens started changing every request in Django 1.10, so I'm not sure why you're seeing a change in behaviour going from 1.11 to 2.1.

Comment: Is there a way to force Django to use the same token? Searching on web Im not finding any solution

Comment: No, there isn't any way to change the behaviour without patching Django. The change was made for security reasons, so you shouldn't try to undo it.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you can't get the cookie value from the cookie, by making a request to a view that uses `@ensure_csrf_cookie decorator`. The cookie value stays the same, it's only the token that changes every request.

Comment: Because in develpment mode, due to different port of server (I suppose), 
 `@ensure_csrf_cookie` doesn't store the cookie on client side. So I have to store manually but if the value changes, when client read the cookie, I will read an old value so when triying to login (for example), Django return an error about CSRF Token.

Comment: I don't have any suggestions for how to solve this in Django. Perhaps you could set up a reverse proxy in development, so that both servers are on the same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot and after the answer of Alasdair, the only solution found is to force Middleware to generate the same token.

This approach is valid only in my development specific situation.

Go to:

```
lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware
```

edit the file

```
csrf.py
```

Edit the definition of method:

```
def _get_token(self, request):
```

before any other instructions, write a return with your token:

```
def _get_token(self, request):
        return "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234"
```